# Tomcat server not starting from myeclipse

Tags: myeclipse, tomcat5.5

Tomcat is running when i run it from startup.bat and my application gets started, but when i run the server from the eclipse I am getting the below error,

```
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
Loading jar:file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
27 Sep 2014 22:15:30,301 INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].log():653 [main] - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Loading jar:file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
Loading jar:file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/captcha.properties
27 Sep 2014 22:15:36,874 INFO com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.<init>():252 [main] - Portal lib directory /D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
27 Sep 2014 22:15:41,076 INFO com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ServerDetector.getServerId():104 [main] - Detected server tomcat
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way by addding the below parameters in optional jvm arguments.(window -> preference -> tomcat 5.x -> JDK)

```
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxNewSize=256m
-XX:NewSize=512m
```